# Powershell Get-Date -Day (New Year)

Tags: .net, powershell

Powershell Get-Date Explanation:

> -Day
>
> Specifies the day of the month that is displayed. Enter a value from 1 to 31. >The default is the current day.
>
> If you specify a value that is greater than the number of days in the month, >PowerShell adds the number of days to the month and displays the result. For >example, "Get-Date -Month 2 -Day 31" displays "March 3", not "February 31".

Will this roll over into new year as well, or do I have to adjust code to detect new year if the date ends up transforming into `January 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not roll over, because December has 31 days and anything higher than 31 is an exception.

```
Get-Date -Month 2 -Day 32
```

Result:

> Get-Date : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Day'. The 32 argument is greater than the maximum allowed range of
>   31.  Supply an argument that is less than or equal to 31 and then try the command again.
>   At line:1 char:24
>   + get-date -month 2 -day 32
>   +
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Date],   ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>    ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand

Same for month 12:

```
Get-Date -Month 12 -Day 32
```

Result

> Get-Date : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Day'. The 32 argument is greater than the maximum allowed range of
>   31.  Supply an argument that is less than or equal to 31 and then try the command again.
>   At line:1 char:24
>   + get-date -month 2 -day 32
>   +
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Date],   ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>    ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand

Comment: Interesting.

I didn't even think about the fact that adding a day would move it into 32, which is out of value.

I guess I have to just systematically adjust each value all the way to year.

Thanks.

Comment: @JacobKucinic - you can get the number of days in any given month thus ... `[datetime]::DaysInMonth(2018, 12)`. [*grin*]

Comment: @JacobKucinic *I guess I have to just systematically adjust each value all the way to year.* Do not reinvent the bicycle. It is already here: `(Get-Date -Month 12 -Day 31) + (New-TimeSpan -Days 1)`.